# Error with declaring a variable?

Tags: java

I am probably just being stupid, but I am attempting to create a variable and am getting this error:

```
Syntax error on token "continue", invalid VariableDeclaratorId
```

The line of code is

```
static boolean continue = false;
```

For some reason if I change the variable name it seems to work, however I would really prefer to use the variable name "continue" because it is easier to remember than "cont" or any other variation, which is important to me.

So, is there any way that I can declare this variable?

Comment: "continue" is a reserved word in Java -- you cannot use it for a variable name.  (Don't feel to bad about this -- yesterday I was hung up for at least 30 minutes because I'd use "event" for a variable name in C#, and the error message was incredibly cryptic.)

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, this is a hard thing for a compiler to diagnose.  In a typical implementation, reserved words are treated as completely different entities than other identifiers and cause the compiler or parser to go down a completely different path, making it pretty hard to get the compiler to see this as an attempt to use the reserved word as a normal identifier.

Answer (score 8):

Continue is a keyword in the Java language, so you cannot use it as a identifier for your variable. Declare the variable you have as

```
static boolean continue = false;
```

You cannot use the variable names as one of the keywords of the language. Otherwise you'll get this error while compiling the code.

If you still want the `continue`, use it as Upper Case. Or change it to something else. But not the continue as it is.

Comment: No sir, you just cant use keywords in your variable names. Otherwise compiler would think you're trying to execute some command here.

Comment: Thank you! Great help. I will most likely go for the upper case option.

I can't accept the answer because "You can accept an answer in 13 minutes", however I will accept the answer then :).

Comment: Yeah its ok. :) You can accept it then. ^_^ Glad I helped you out buddy!

Comment: Upper-casing the name will solve the problem, but could be a little distracting for a reader, since upper-case names are mostly used as constants or `enum` objects under the standard Java coding conventions.  I tend to use names like `needToContinue` or `willContinue`, which are more descriptive than `continue` would be even if it were allowed.

Comment: @ajb, Upper case are also used as the `Class` identifiers too. :)

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan I interpreted "use it as Upper Case" to mean _all_ upper-case, i.e. `CONTINUE`.  If that isn't what you meant, my apologies.  But using `Continue` as a variable could be distracting also, since that kind of identifier looks like a class name.  Just my opinion.

Comment: @ajb, You interpreted it corrected, I did mention it as `CONTINUE`, which is also known as Constant value in Java! :D

Answer (score 0):

`continue` is a predefined keyword in `Java`.

You cannot use varaiableName as reserved keywords.

[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_keywords) shows the list of keywords in Java

Answer (score 0):

The *javadoc* says **Also keep in mind that the name you choose must not be a keyword or reserved word.**

As [`continue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) is a keyword in the Java language, so you can never use it as a identifier for your variable.